# Waterproof microphone

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I want to shoot the following scene in amateur video: man jumps into the waterpool, swims under the water a couple of meters, and then floats back. The scene should be shot on head-mounted camera (which is inside a waterproof case).

The problem is I am not satisfied by the camera microphone sound. I would like to attach to man some other microphone (connected to audio recorder which is inside waterproof case in person's pocket). What microphone can I use for this case? Should it be some special waterproof mic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) You could waterproof an existing mic. Many do this by using a non-lubricated condom.

2) You could buy a hydraphone, but that might be more expensive than you'd like for an amateur project.

Both of these options (as well as building your own hydraphone) are described in more detail [on this page](http://www.phonography.org/water.htm) at phonography.org

3) You may purchase or find royalty-free sounds for a foley track.

Comment: +1 for the condom. I've done that with an RE-10 on MANY occasions.

Comment: +1 for the condom suggestion, which is good, time-tested advice. I think ultimately designing the sound will read as more 'real' then what you will record with any mic.